# Remove any CGPath points out of view of the camera in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am using the path make make an SKShapeNode, and if the path gets too long the application terminates from memory issues. How can you remove points from a CGPath that have left the view of the camera?

Comment: You can't remove elements from a CGPath. You'll need to store the points in an array, remove the hidden ones, and create a new path.

Comment: Subclass/add an extension to CGPath and add a property for the array of points and a method to return the path from the array excluding any points outside of the view.